# Exception "Create pooled connection during start failed" when using two connection pools with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, activemq-classic

So my use case is this: 
I have a set of Camel (2.14) routes, which polls a couple of data base tables, does some transformations and then puts messages on different ActiveMQ (5.10.0) queues. For this I've set up a connection pool like described in the [Camel wiki](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html):

```
<!-- ActiveMQ Connection Pooling-->
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMQConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="activemqConfig"
      class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
</bean>


<bean id="activemq"
      class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="activemqConfig"/>
</bean>
```

I'm currently developing an additional set of Camel components, which will fetch data from some of the ActiveMQ queues, and push the messages forward to some JMS Topics. These topics are based on OracleAQ, and my current setup is this:

```
<!-- AQ JMS -->
<bean id="connectionFactoryOracleAQ" class="oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory"
      factory-method="getQueueConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>${rib.host}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String">
        <value>${rib.sid}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" type="int">
        <value>${rib.port}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3">
        <value>${rib.driverType}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="credentials"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref bean="connectionFactoryOracleAQ"/>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${aq.user}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${aq.pass}</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="credentials"/>
</bean>
```

Unfortunately the sending to OracleAQ is painfully slow. The to() step in my camel routes takes roughly 2,5 seconds, which is not good enough. So I thought I'd set up a second connection pool to see if things improved, so I changed to setup for the connection factory to this::

```
<!-- AQ JMS -->
<bean id="connectionFactoryOracleAQ" class="oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory"
      factory-method="getQueueConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>${rib.host}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String">
        <value>${rib.sid}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" type="int">
        <value>${rib.port}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3">
        <value>${rib.driverType}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="credentials"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref bean="connectionFactoryOracleAQ"/>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${aq.user}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${aq.pass}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--  ActiveMQ Connection Pooling for AQ -->
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactoryAq"
      class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="credentials" />
</bean>

<bean id="activemqConfigAq"
      class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactoryAq"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="activemqAq"
      class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="activemqConfigAq"/>
</bean>
```

However when starting my routes with ActiveMQ, I'm now seeing the exception below. I'm doing anything wrong here? The log says that the exception will be ignored, but I don't feel like ignoring it without atleast understanding why it's being thrown:

```
2014-10-09 20:50:43,783 | INFO  | Connector vm://localhost started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2014-10-09 20:50:44,760 | WARN  | Create pooled connection during start failed. This exception will be ignored. | org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory | WrapperSimpleAppMain
javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createJmsException(PooledConnectionFactory.java:247)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:202)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:181)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.start(PooledConnectionFactory.java:267)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1640)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[integration-routes-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_45]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)[wrapper.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: Regarding the 2nd connection factory, I'm assuming you have a connection factory bean called  "credentials" and everything there is correct?  In regards to the slowness, I've not checked, but its possible that Camel is still aggressively creating connections, rather than filling the max sessions first.  You can try reducing max connections to 1 and possibly increasing maximumActiveSessionPerConnection. I had a similar issue that ended up being because camel was creating new connections rather than using available connection pool connections.

Comment: Yes, I still have the same one as in the first example. I've updated my question to more clearly reflect this.